# How to open quickfix window below vertical splits?

Tags: vim

I usually use several vertical splits so that each has a width of not much more than 80 characters (the code I work on tends to follow the 80 column limit). However, that's usually not enough for a quickfix or a location window. Is there any way to open it below all vertical splits, like this?

```
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
| quickfix     |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that using autocmds:

```
au FileType qf wincmd J
```

`wincmd foo` is equivalent with typing `^W foo`, and CTRL-W_J moves the current window to the very bottom. `au FileType qf` executes this for every file with the filetype "qf" (quickfix).